# Monitoring server disk space usage

Tags: windows, web-server

I came across a problem this morning where my server went offline, I spent a lot of the morning trying to diagnose the issue It turns out that the server was not accessible due to having no available disk space left This was caused by the fact that the server had held on to over 100GB worth of back up files. The server runs a back up every month and is only supposed to hold on to the one which it has done and the most recent 2 before this one. there was an issue and it had been holding on to all of the back ups

I was wondering if there was any software which would allow me to monitor the disk space usage of my server from a GUI on my desktop. I had seen Disk Space Analyzer - Baobab but it appears that this is a linux only program and I am using windows 10

I have also found a number of similar software options but it appears that they only offer the ability to monitor your own local hard drive

Answer (score 0):

One quick and dirty way could be to map the admin share (eg C$) of the server on your computer. You can then see disk space utilisation through Explorer, or even use RainMeter and other software to monitor it.

[image]

Comment: thank you for your response. I have tried this but having no joy.
I opened the `This PC` folder and clicked to add `Network Location`
I then used `ftp://username.password@ipaddress:port/`
But it does not let me connect
Is there a better way that you know of?

Answer (score 0):

The answer you are looking for is Netdata (https://www.netdata.cloud/) An open source cross platform monitoring tool giving you real time information on over 200 different system components and resources. While it is mainly used for Linux servers, it can be deployed on Windows relatively easy. I believe there is also a guide on how to do it on Windows. Highly recommended.